# Advanced find in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I really suck at Rails' finders besides the most obvious. I always resort to SQL when things get more advanced than

```
Model.find(:all, :conditions => ['field>? and field<? and id in (select id from table)', 1,2])
```

I have this method:

```
def self.get_first_validation_answer(id)
a=find_by_sql("
  select answers.*, answers_registrations.answer_text
  from answers_registrations left join answers on answers_registrations.answer_id=answers.id
  where 
    (answers_registrations.question_id in (select id from questions where validation_question=true)) 
    and
    (sale_registration_id=#{id})
  limit 1
").first

a.answer_text || a.text if a
end
```

Can someone create a find method that gets me what I want?

Regards,

Jacob

Comment: How are your models defined? What are the associations (belongs_to, has_many, etc.)?

Comment: Not an answer, but i see that you are doing variable interpolation in your find_by_sql call to place the ID as a parameter to your where statement. This approach is prone to SQL injection.
Try to use the following to prevent that:
find_by_sql ['select... where... and sale_registration_id = ?', id]

Comment: Faisal > I know - I modified the example and just chose the easy way. Thanks for the tip, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class AnswersRegistration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end

id = 123
the_reg = AnswersRegistration.first(
  :joins => :answers, 
  :conditions => '(question_id in (select id from questions where validation_question = true)) and (sale_registration_id = ?)', id)
```

*(untested)*

Comment: Thanks - that is as Rails-like as it gets? I have no problem doing it that way - I just thought that one could to it almost without writing any real SQL at all. 

You just do ":joins" - how does Rails know that it should be a left join?

Comment: By default, `:joins` uses an inner join. To do a left join, you have to specify some sql: `:joins => "left join answers on answers_registrations.answer_id=answers.id"`

Answer (score 0):

Just use binarylogic's Searchlogic gem if that satisfies your need.
Here you go: http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that there are gems and plugins that can help but for some reason I like to use the stock stuff where possible - so I would like the original question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes AR will choke on complicated nested conditions, but in theory you should be able to do this:

```
AnswersRegistration.first(:conditions => { :question => { :validation_question => true },
                                           :sale_registration_id => id },
                          :include => :answer)
```